# L2E these two are the same thing?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Are the following two statements the same?

```
Users user = db.Users.First(u => (u.Username == username));
```

and

```
var user = from u in db.Users
          where u.Username == username
          select u;
Users aUser = user.First();
```

Comment: Note that neither one is probably correct. I think you actually want `u.Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both of those queries are identical in function.  The compiler will actually take the second query and translate it into the first query as the LINQ language keywords are simply a language extension to C#.

Here is a similar example that shows this to be true:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var names = new[] { "Andrew", "Nicole", "Michael",
            "Joe", "Sammy", "Joshua" };

        var shortNames = from n in names
               where n.Length == 6
               select n;
        var first = names.First();
    }
}
```

Using Reflector I was able to see the actual compiled code:

```
internal class Example
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        string[] names = new string[] { "Andrew", "Nicole", "Michael", "Joe", "Sammy", "Joshua" };
        IEnumerable<string> shortNames = names.Where<string>(delegate (string n) {
            return n.Length == 6;
        });
        string first = names.First<string>();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the query syntax I typed was changed by the compiler to call the extension methods from the `Enumerable` class.  The LINQ query keywords are simply a convenience to the developer that the compiler converts into method calls.

**Edit:** I did notice one difference between your two queries that I didn't notice at first glance.  Your first query will execute slightly faster since it passes a predicate to the `First` method.  This will be faster since your second query uses the `Where` method first to filter the results and then grabs the first record.  The second query uses two method calls while the first one uses only one.